# UICollectionView Repeats and Reorders Cell Content When Refreshed

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

I'm trying to work through the iTunes U CS193P iOS programming course. I'm running into some issues using `UICollectionView` to display cards as a part of the Set game implementation. I'm seeing a very odd behavior when clicking on a card causing the `UICollectionView` to refresh. Contents will be reordered and sometimes repeated in the view. See two examples of before and afters [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tV5Y.jpg).

I'm fairly certain this has to do with my `UICollectionView` implementation as the game logic has been tested using buttons.

Tap code in the "view controller":

```
- (IBAction)touchCard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [sender locationInView:self.cardCollectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.cardCollectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:tapLocation];
    if (indexPath) {
        [self.game chooseCardatIndex:indexPath.item];
        [self updateUI];
    }
}
```

The `updateUI` code:

```
- (void)updateUI
{
    // Reload data for cardCollectionView
    [self.cardCollectionView reloadData];

    // For each cell within the UICollectionViewCell
    for (UICollectionViewCell *cell in [self.cardCollectionView visibleCells]) {

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.cardCollectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
        Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        if([card isKindOfClass:[SetCard class]]) {
            SetCard *setcard = (SetCard *)card;
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"index %d updated with %d,%d,%d,%d",indexPath.item,setcard.rank,setcard.color,setcard.shape,setcard.pattern]);
            // Updates individual cards for each cardCollectionView
            [self updateCell:cell usingCard:card animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

This updates the cell view:

```
- (void)updateCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell usingCard:(Card *)card animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    setCardView *cardView = ((setCardCellView *)cell).setCardV;

    if([card isKindOfClass:[SetCard class]]) {
        SetCard *setCard = (SetCard *)card;

        // Set attributes of the card in the cardView
        cardView.rank = setCard.rank;
        cardView.shape = setCard.shape;
        cardView.pattern = setCard.pattern;
        cardView.color = setCard.color;

        // Set chosen cards
        cardView.selected = setCard.isChosen;
    }
}
```

Finally the `collectionView` required method `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:[self reuseIdentifier] forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Card *card = [self.game cardAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    [self updateCell:cell usingCard:card animated:YES];
    return cell;
}
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement a cellForRowAtIndexPath / cellForItemAtIndexPath method, you have to fully configure every cell that you get back from the dequeue method.

Your code is only configuring the cell if the card object for that row is of type SetCard. If the card object is not a SetCard, you leave the cell alone. That means that if the cell you get from your dequeue method was previously used to display a SetCard, but the card object is not a SetCard, the cell's views won't get changed, and will still show the old values.

Add an else clause to your if statement that sets the fields back to their default state if the card object is not of class SetCard.

Comment: I added an else clause that outputs to log if not SetCard class. Unfortunately, in testing, the else clause is never executed, still seeing the same behavior of cells being re-ordered and duplicated.